# The catch clause in Promise.all doesn't work

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to load bunch of text files using multiple fetch requests via `Promise.all`. Here's how it looks:

```
////////////////////////////////////////
const loadTextFiles = (allUrls, textUrls) => {
    const requests = textUrls.map(url => fetch(url));
    return Promise.all(requests)
           .then(responses => Promise.all(
                 responses.map(response => response.text())
           ))  
           .then(texts => texts.forEach(
               (text, i) => allUrls[textUrls[i]] = text
           ))  
           .catch(err => {
               // log("HERE");
               throw exception("networkLoader",
                               "loadTextFiles",
                               `error in loadTextFiles: ${err.toString()}`);
           });
};
```

`allUrls` and `textUrls` are two arrays that contain the urls of all resources (files with any extension) and text resources (files with .txt extension), respectively. In fact, `textUrls` is constructed from `allUrls` (never mind why or how). The results are stored inside the allUrls array. For example, if `allUrls = [ "image.png", "essay.txt" ]` , then `textUrls = [ "essay.txt" ]` . Now, if I call `loadTextFiles`:

```
await loadTextFiles(allUrls, textUrls);
```

I will get access to the contents of "essay.txt" by accessing `allUrls["essay.txt"]`. Things are okay so long as all text files exist and can be retrieved.
The problem is, despite the fact that I have written a `catch` to detect problems in Promise.all, it doesn't work. For instance, if I request *fileThatDoesNotExist.txt* I get a *404 (Not Found)* in the browser console but my code inside catch doesn't run. I tested it even with a custom `log` function which also doesn't run. I'd like to catch the error and re-throw it. How do I do that?

Edit: When I said "I'd like to catch the error" I meant that I want to get notified of *404 error* and throw an exception (in this case a custom `exception` object)

Comment: You should read the fetch manual how to use fetch correctly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: `fetch()` will reject only if there is a network problem. Getting an error code like 404 will not reject the promise. You have to check the `ok` flag on the response for those.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved in the following way:

```
const loadTextFiles = (allUrls, textUrls) => {
    const requests = textUrls.map(url => fetch(url));
    return Promise.all(requests)
           .then(responses => Promise.all(
                 responses.map(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.text();
                    }
                    throw exception("networkLoader",
                                    "loadTextFiles",
                                    `couldn't load ${response.url}`);
                 })
           ))
           .then(texts => texts.forEach(
               (text, i) => allUrls[textUrls[i]] = text
           ))
           .catch(err => {
               if (exception.isException(err)) {
                   throw err;
               }
               throw exception("networkLoader",
                               "loadTextFiles",
                               `error: ${err.toString()}`);
           });
};
```

We test each response returned by fetch by checking its `ok` property, and if this property is false, then an exception is thrown.